# jquery - select / filter items in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, filter, gallery

I have an image gallery that id like to be able to sort by album.

I have an array like :

```
var images_gallery = [
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-1.jpg",
        album: "xmas"
    },
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-2.jpg",
        album: "xmas"
    },
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-3.jpg",
        album: "xmas"
    },
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-4.jpg",
         album: "summer"
    }
]
```

i also have a select in my html:

```
   <select name="album">
        <option selected="selected" id="all">All</option>
        <option id="xmas">Xmas Party</option>
        <option id="summer">Summer Party</option>
    </select>
```

and then this in my js file:

```
$("select[name='album']").change(function() {
    var thisAlbum = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
});
```

my question is, how do I filter my array by album that matches my select options id (and then display them, which I have a function for (showImages) ).

EDIT:

using the answers below ive gotten here:

```
$("select[name='album']").change(function() {
    var thisAlbum = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

    var filteredArray = images_gallery.filter(function(x) {
        return x.album == thisAlbum;
    });

    $('#librarian-page-container-gallery').html(' ');

    Shadowbox.setup("a.gallery", {
        gallery:   "gallery",
    });

    filteredArray.showImages2();


});
```

im not sure how to apply my function to the new filtered array though?

my function looks like:

```
function showImages2(){
$.each(images_gallery,function(i,image_gallery){
           // stuff in here
    });
}
```

thanks for your help so far!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter items in JavaScript Array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085012/filter-items-in-javascript-array-using-jquery)

Comment: *"im not sure how to apply my function to the new filtered array though?"* Pass the array to `showImages2` as **argument**. Have a look at how functions work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: so if my array is stored in var'result', would i not do: $.each(result,function(b,image_gallery2){} ? only this doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your array using `filter`:

```
var filteredArray = images_array.filter(function(x) {
   return x.album == thisAlbum;
});
```

[Here's a shim](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm) for support in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Using David's answer to filter the results.

```
$("select[name='album']").change(function() {
    var thisAlbum = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    var result = images_gallery.filter(function(x) {
       return x.album == thisAlbum;
    });
    //Clear images
    $('#images').html(' ');
    //Show images in new result array
    for(img in result){
        $('#images').append('<img src="' + result[img].image_src + '" />');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vyaTC/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery you could use [`.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var filterArray = $.grep(images_gallery, function(obj) {
    return obj.album === thisAlbum;
});
```

did a change on thisAlbum if its 'all' then get all objects in the array: http://jsfiddle.net/4tEz4/

```
var filterArray = $.grep(images_gallery, function(obj) {
    return thisAlbum === 'all' || obj.album === thisAlbum;
});
```

or just:

```
var filterArray = thisAlbum === 'all' ? images_gallery : $.grep(images_gallery, function(obj) {
    return obj.album === thisAlbum;
});
```