# Filter specific items in array

Tags: jquery

I use jquery tokeninput to fill my inputs with data from the server for example:

```
$(".input").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
            prePopulate: [{id: 123, name: "Slurms MacKenzie"}],
        });
```

So now i have the problem that i want to fill several input on a site with specific data, so i changed my code a little bit:

```
<input type="text" id="1" class="input" name="blah" />
<input type="text" id="2" class="input" name="blah" />

        var array =  [
            {id: 123, name: "Smith", input: "1"},
            {id: 156, name: "Kanye", input: "2"},
            {id: 134, name: "MacKenzie", input: "1"}
            ]

     $(".input").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
            prePopulate: array
        });
```

How you can see i added in the array `input` where the `id` od the input is defiend the item should be appendend to, for example:

```
 {id: 156, name: "Kanye", input: "2"}
```

Should be only assigend to input with `id 2`

**So how can i filter only the entries of the array where $(this).attr("id") has the same value as input: in array?**

Thanks fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v394w/7/

Comment: Sorry this is the right fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v394w/7/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter items in JavaScript Array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085012/filter-items-in-javascript-array-using-jquery)

Comment: The problem is that it has several variables `id,name,input` i dont know how to transpose it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab each `.input`, filter the array for the corresponding `id` with [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) and initialize `tokenInput` with the filtered array

```
var array =  [
    {id: 123, name: "Smith", input: "1"},
    {id: 156, name: "Kanye", input: "2"},
    {id: 134, name: "MacKenzie", input: "1"}
];

$(".input").each(function(_, item) {
    var filtered= $.grep(array, function(el) {
                        return el.input == item.id;
                    });

    $(this).tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
        prePopulate: filtered
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24MVh/)